# Apple now says you have to have iPhone turned on to get iMessages on all devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

iMac Pro - 10.15.3, iPad 13.3 and iPhone 13.3.1. This AM I noticed that when I did some logging in to different sites, that I have text message 2 step verification turned on, I was not getting the iMessage verification code. Tried multiple sites and times - no iMessages. So, I had to get the codes via iPhone.  I was using an iPad and I got no iMessage on it or my MacBook Pro.  Later on I went to the kitchen and turned on my iPhone and viola, I get all these iMessages with codes coming through which then all go to my other devices.  In talking to Apple the senior tech she tried to get me to update my devices - which I refused - gonna wait a bit on that - but she also said you have to have the most current software on all devices and have all devices on or text forwarding won't work.

This makes no sense to me.  Anyone else having iMessages not forwarding issues?

Comment: pure guess - Check you have more than one contact method in you iMessage setup. On the Mac, Messages > Prefs >iMessage > you can be reached at… My primary is my phone number, but I also have my iCloud address

Comment: my primary is my phone number.  It makes no sense to me to have to have your iPhone on to get messages to your computer and iPad.  What if one doesn't own an iPhone but has an iPad?  How to you get messages then?  I cant believe apple changed this!

Comment: Yes, but as per the question @Tetsujin was asking, do you have anything else listed besides just your mobile number? In my case, I have my mobile number listed as well as the Apple ID I am logged into iCloud with.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I did not see that it was question?  I did check as mentioned and I do have TTL 3 method of contact but my ph as primary and only one checked - the ph number.  Does it make a difference in operation to have more than 1 method and only 1 being checked?  Tks

Comment: I've never tested it, but it would be reasonable to assume that if you can only be contacted on your phone number & the phone is off, there is no alternate way to contact you.

Comment: seems weird as this has never happened before.  I can send a text and get them to my computer with my phone off

Answer (score 1):

so it happened again with the bank agin this am - phone turned off, no verification iMessage received on the iPad or computer even though at about the exact same time I received some iMessage/texts from others....  I decided to call the bank this time and not apple.  The banks response seems reasonable------

the message they send are what the guy called, short code carrier messages and bc the associated number, my cell, was turned off the message is not received and therefore cannot be synced through iMessage to other devices. Makes more sense than what apple told me.